# Why do these commands produce different outputs?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, pipe, date

I am trying to get the linux timestamp from a row of text.  I can use the `cut` command to grab the string

```
> echo '"tester_row_____",0,"2016-07-04T01:42:28Z","2016-07-04T02:00:58Z"' | cut -c 22-41
2016-07-04T01:42:28Z
```

Now, if I use that date string directly in a call to date I can get the linux timestamp

```
> date +"%s" --date 2016-07-04T01:42:28Z
1467596548
```

However, if I pipe the results of the `cut` command into the `date` command I get different results

```
> echo '"tester_row_____",0,"2016-07-04T01:42:28Z","2016-07-04T02:00:58Z"' | cut -c 22-41 | date +"%s" --date -
1467590400
```

Why are the results different?

Comment: in some quick tests, `date --date -` does not accept standard input, try `date +"%s" --date $(echo '"tester_row_____",0,"2016-07-04T01:42:28Z","2016-07-04T02:00:58Z"' | cut -c 22-41)`

Comment: Nice, thanks that worked.  If you answer the question I can mark it answered.

Comment: You're using `--date` with an empty date string (the trailing dash is ignored) e.g. same as doing `...| date +"%s" --date='' -` . Now, if you used `xargs` to pass input to `date` it should work, e.g. if you pipe it to `...| xargs date +"%s" --date`. You have to use the option `-f` with `-` to have `date` read directly from _stdin_ e.g.  `...| date +"%s" -f -`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`date --date -` does not accept standard input; try `date +"%s" --date "$(echo '"tester_row_____",0,"2016-07-04T01:42:28Z","2016-07-04T02:00:58Z"' | cut -c 22-41)"` instead.  This will run your string manipulation pipeline in a subshell, and use the output of that as a parameter for `date`.